# Access meteor app using a different URL

Tags: meteor, iron-router

Normally I access my meteor app as follows

```
http://localhost:3000
```

Now I want to run it with a path appended, like this

```
http://localhost:3000/meteor
```

This has some implications and I'm not sure what the best solution is. First I hoped it would work out-of-the-box by adding the environment variable ROOT_URL

```
$> export ROOT_URL='http://localhost:3000/meteor'
```

But no :(

All the public resources now return 404s. For example, I removed the first slash, going from

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">
```

to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
```

but that didn't change anything (shouldn't this has solved that problem ?) still 404s!

Also, the routes don't seem to work too. So I guess that I also need the add '/meteor' to all the routes. Does anyone know how to fix the 404s and maybe knows an easier way to deal with this ?

Comment: Why are you manually loading your css files? Meteor automatically adds whatever css you have in your client directory

Comment: One reason, for example, is a css file from select2. My bower components are in the public section so I've included it as described above.

Comment: It seems that appending `./` to each path fixes the problem, weird!

Comment: Right because ./ runs in the current directory versus /whatever in the root

Comment: Well, I would say that `css/styles.css` should behave identical to `./css/styles.css`

Comment: I just got it working without ROOT_URL and the absolute paths